# Kotlin Reflection check if class property is ArrayList of specific type

Tags: kotlin, reflection, typechecking

I'm a bit new with Kotlin and Java and have following question: how to check if reflected property type is ArrayList of specific type, for example is ArrayList<Pair<String, ByteArray>>?

Code behind:

```
        class DataUploadFormData {
            var files: ArrayList<Pair<String, ByteArray>> = arrayListOf()
            var collection: String? = null
        }

        // DataUploadFormData type is passed here as T
        suspend inline fun <reified T : Any> mapFormData(data: MultiPartData): T? {
            val formData: FormData = getFormData(data)
            val model: T? = getValue()
            var fields = T::class.memberProperties
            fields.forEach { field ->
                if (field is KMutableProperty<*>) {
                    setFieldValue(field, formData, model)
                }
            }

            return model
        }


        @OptIn(ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)
        fun <T> setFieldValue(field: KMutableProperty<*>, formData: FormData, model: T?) {
            var value: Any? = null

            if (field.returnType.javaType == String::class.createType().javaType ||
                field.returnType.javaType == Int::class.createType().javaType ||
                field.returnType.javaType == Double::class.createType().javaType
            ) {
                value = formData.fields.firstOrNull(predicate = { it.first == field.name })?.second
            }
            else if (
            // check if field.returnType is of ArrayList<Pair<String, ByteArray>> type?
            ) {
                value = formData.files
            }

            field.setter.call(model, value)
        }
```

Checking simple data types works well but have no idea how to check if reflected property is of complex types. I tried to instantiate property and use `is` or `instanceof` but I couldn't instantiate property with code like that `field.returnType.javaType::class.createInstance()`. Check `field.returnType.classifier is ArrayList<*>` returns false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`typeOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/type-of.html) to get a `KType` representing the type you want to check against, and use `==` to compare.

```
if (field.returnType == typeOf<ArrayList<Pair<String, ByteArray>>>()) {
    // ...
}
```

You can do this for those "simple types" too.

This only checks the *declared* returned type of the property, not whether the property actually holds an instance of `ArrayList<Pair<String, ByteArray>>`. Therefore, if the field was declared as:

```
var field: ArrayList<*> = arrayListOf(
    "foo" to byteArrayOf()
)
```

The check would fail. The declared type of the field is `ArrayList<*>`, but it can be said that it actually holds a `ArrayList<Pair<String, ByteArray>>`.

You cannot reliably check if the type of the instance that the field holds, because of type erasure.